# Firebase filtered query with laravel

Tags: laravel, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I want to search users from friebase just like we use **LIKE** in mysql to get related results.
if someone enter **asi** the returning result should be all users which should contain **asi** in their firstname or lastname.

Is there any way to do it? i read all the documentation by firebase but could not find solution for this.

Answer (score 0):

You can fetch data something like by passing full name or Email.

```
$user = $firebase->getReference("users/{$uid}")
           ->orderByChild("email")
           ->equalTo("mail@mail.com")
           ->getSnapshot();
```

or you can use startAt so you can search with startAt keyword.

```
->orderByChild("email")
->startAt("mail@mail.com")
```

You can use similar functionality first() like laravel query

```
->limittoFirst(1);
```

You can follow this query :

```
->orderByChild("email")
->startAt("asi")
->endAt("[a-zA-Z0-9]*")
```

Comment: Thank you for reply. But my Question was not about that. i already done that.

Comment: Please read my question again.

Comment: I want to implement search functionality and for that i am thinking to get all users the way we get users using mysql LIKE query. .. and by example i describe it in my Question.

Comment: This .equalTo() works on === comparison

Comment: please check second one startAt

Comment: Ashish can you please tell me pattern for name. user1.firstname = asif   user2.firstname=masifa user3.firstname=ahtisham.

so when someone search asi result should return user1 and user2

Comment: i think if i use startAt() then it will only return asif  it will not return masifa

Comment: Then you have proceed with logic. Something like get all data then provide some logins like name.Contains("asi").

Comment: you are saying first we will get all users from firebase and then will perform php  string functions to check required characters exist or not in name. ? did i got it right?

Comment: yes That's only way there is no contains functionality